# Get details from System Catalog in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to find the following information on all user defined tables in a SINGLE query in Oracle11g:

1. Table name
2. Column name
3. Constraint name
4. Constraint type - Use 'PK', 'FK', 'CK' and 'NN' instead of 1 letter codes
5. Search Condition for any Check (CK) constraints
6. Table and Column that each FK references

So far, I have managed this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables ORDER BY table_name;

TABLE_NAME
---------------
CLIENT
EMPLOYEE
FAULTREPORT
OUTLET
RAGREEMENT
VEHICLE

SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
FROM user_constraints 
WHERE table_name IN ('CLIENT','EMPLOYEE','FAULTREPORT','OUTLET','RAGREEMENT','VEHICLE')
ORDER BY table_name;


TABLE_NAME      CONSTRAINT_NAME                C SEARCH_CONDITION
--------------- ------------------------------ - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLIENT          CLIENT_CLIENTNAME_NN           C clientName IS NOT NULL
CLIENT          CLIENT_STREET_NN               C street IS NOT NULL
CLIENT          CLIENT_CITY_NN                 C city IS NOT NULL
CLIENT          CLIENT_STATE_NN                C state IS NOT NULL
CLIENT          CLIENT_EMAIL_CK                C REGEXP_LIKE(email,'^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$','i') AND email IS NOT
                                                  NULL

CLIENT          CLIENT_PHONE_CK                C REGEXP_LIKE(phone,'^(\(\d{3}\))([[:blank:]])\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}(-)\d{3}(-)\d{4}$
                                                 |^\d{10}$')
                                                                                                                  AND phone IS NOT NULL

CLIENT          CLIENT_CLIENTNO_PK             P
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_LNAME_NN              C lname IS NOT NULL
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_NUM_PK                P
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_OUTLET_NUM_FK         R
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_FNAME_NN              C fname IS NOT NULL
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_DOB_CK                C hireDate >= ADD_MONTHS(dob, 216)
EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_PHONE_CK              C REGEXP_LIKE(phone,'^(\(\d{3}\))([[:blank:]])\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}(-)\d{3}(-)\d{4}$
                                                 |^\d{10}$')
                                                                                                               AND phone IS NOT NULL

EMPLOYEE        EMPLOYEE_GENDER_CK             C gender in ('MALE', 'FEMALE')
FAULTREPORT     FAULTREPORT_DATECHECKED_NN     C dateChecked IS NOT NULL
FAULTREPORT     FAULTREPORT_REPORTNUM_PK       P
FAULTREPORT     FAULTREPORT_EMPLOYEE_NUM_FK    R
FAULTREPORT     FAULTREPORT_RENTAL_NUM_FK      R
FAULTREPORT     FAULTREPORT_LICENSENO_NN       C licenseNo IS NOT NULL
OUTLET          OUTLET_STREET_NN               C street IS NOT NULL
OUTLET          OUTLET_NUM_PK                  P
OUTLET          OUTLET_STATE_NN                C state IS NOT NULL
OUTLET          OUTLET_ZIPCODE_NN              C zipCode IS NOT NULL
OUTLET          OUTLET_PHONE_CK                C REGEXP_LIKE(phone,'^(\(\d{3}\))([[:blank:]])\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}(-)\d{3}(-)\d{4}$
                                                 |^\d{10}$')
                                                                                                                AND phone IS NOT NULL

OUTLET          OUTLET_CITY_NN                 C city IS NOT NULL
OUTLET          OUTLET_MGR_NUM_FK              R
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_CLIENT_NUM_FK       R
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_LICENSE_NUM_FK      R
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_MILEAGE_CK          C mileagebefore < mileageafter
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_INSURANCETYPE_NN    C insurancetype IS NOT NULL
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_PK                  P
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_STARTDATE_NN        C startdate IS NOT NULL
RAGREEMENT      RAGREEMENT_MILEAGEBEFORE_NN    C mileagebefore IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_DAILYRATE_NN           C dailyrate IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_MODEL_NN               C model IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_MAKE_NN                C make IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         SYS_C0010620                   C "LICENSENO" IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_LICENSE_NUM_PK         P
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_YEAR_CK                C EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year) > 2005 AND year IS NOT NULL
VEHICLE         VEHICLE_OUT_NUM_FK             R

40 rows selected.
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply use

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
  FROM user_constraints 
 WHERE table_name IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
 ORDER BY table_name;
```

or

```
SELECT UT.table_name, UC.constraint_name, UC.constraint_type 
  FROM user_tables UT 
       INNER JOIN user_constraints UC ON UT.table_name = UC. table_name
 ORDER BY UT.table_name;
```

This will give you details about all the tables `you own`.

Now, if you want the details about all tables your account has access to, you can use

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
  FROM user_constraints 
 WHERE table_name IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables)
 ORDER BY table_name;
```

or

```
SELECT AT.table_name, UC.constraint_name, UC.constraint_type 
  FROM all_tables AT 
       INNER JOIN user_constraints UC ON AT.table_name = UC. table_name
 ORDER BY AT.table_name;
```

**EDITED** : If you want to see all column names and the constraint details if any, use the below (untested)

```
SELECT UTC.table_name
       , UTC.column_name
       , UC.constraint_name
       , UC.constraint_type
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS UTC  
       LEFT JOIN user_constraints UC ON UTC.table_name = UC. table_name
 ORDER BY UTC.table_name;
```

Comment: What about all the columns in the table and those that have a constraint on it?

Comment: It gives me a combination of all columns and constraints.